# If else loop in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

There are 3 set of records which I want to capture from an external excel sheet to follow the data driven approach. Scenario: There are 5 fields in the online screen: Grp No/Blclass/Bnk Code/Brnc Code and Acct No.

Now upon providing the grp and blclass and click on "Create", then the other 3 fields will get enabled for data input and when data input done for all fields, the clicking on submit will successfully complete the transaction input for a particular row from external excel.Then it will pick the second record from excel and do the same and so on... Now the scenario is Suppose for the second record,if the acct no is wrong, then it will show an online error and will not allow user to "Submit". At the same time, the header section(grp and billing class) will not be enabled for inputting the next data until user click the exit button because of that online error.

Now I am new in Robot Framework and tried with "Run Keyword If" but somehow it did not work.

Here are the code that I have used. If all the data in the excel are correct, then it will input the transaction one by one for all rows. But,if any wrong data found, my purpose is to skip that input and proceed for the next record as below.

Objective after clicking Submit Button:

If error found, click Exit button and input the next record - as without exit, the header fields will not be enabled for data input

Else input the next record as per loop

[image]

Comment: show your code trials

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the code directly into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
Run Keyword If  '<condition1>' == '<value1>'
...  ELSEIF '<condition2>' == '<value2>'
...  ELSE  <value3>
```

This works for me.